# My website shows up as a blank page on my desktop

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I have been developing a wordpress theme on my laptop and all is well, however when I checked it on my desktop today all that loads is a blank page.  I have asked a couple friends to see if it loads for them and they all say that it does.

I am really not sure how it will not load on this computer, I've cleared the cache/cookies and reset the ip, still blank.  I need to figure out what is going on quickly before this is supposed to be done.

The website url is http://bbmthemes.com/themes/modular/, the top left logo should be broken, other than that everything should work.

Can you think of anything that would make one computer not display anything but a blank page or what I could try to fix this?

Thanks so much

***EDIT***  It displays blank in all browsers (firefox, chrome, ie9) on this desktop, and works in all browsers  on the laptop.  Also, I had already enabled phpconfig and checked for php errors before I noticed this.  I had removed all php errors about a week ago and they were only minor things anyway.  Very confused.  Does it work for you guys even?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? I bet you don't and you're getting a fatal PHP error.

Comment: Which browser here and there?

Comment: Did you check in your _error log_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on the wordpress debugging in `wp-config.php` file and run again to check is there any fatal error or not:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

And be sure that error reporting is `On`

Maybe you are not in right path. I found this theme on your host refer to modular theme: http://bbmthemes.com/themes/smart/

Comment: Yes, that is my development version.  The correctly named one is the newer install for the live version.  The dev version works on both computers.

Comment: This way, without any code review, It's difficult to understanding what's the problem.

Comment: It was a newly added php file causing the problem, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Very frequent, this kind of problems arise because of the environment differences. You should check whether in php.ini short_open_tag=On is on or not. That might cause the problem. Also if your desktop machine is on the Linux machine php5-mysql package comes separately from php5 package.

Also as already mention you have to check log file.

In Ubuntu the location is - /var/log/apache2
On windows - the same directory where apache2 is installed.