# Cpanel shows blank page on my site.

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have a domain on cpanel that i have been using for the past three weeks. However today I logged in to the File Manager and deleted the WordPress files that were previously there (did not remove cgi-bin). I then replaced these files with another instance of the WordPress site then made the necessary changes to the database and config files e.t.c. But when I visit the site through Google Chrome, it shows a blank white screen. I try to visit it using Mozilla and it shows the Old files that I had already deleted. I tried to use my phone(Internet Explorer) to visit the same site and it still shows the Old Site and yet I have already deleted the files. I then removed all the files and uploaded a completely new instance of WordPress freshly downloaded from wordpress.org. I created a database so I could do the install in cpanel but it still shows the blank page on Google Chrome and the old site on Mozilla and on my Phone(Internet Explorer). I have tried quite a number of suggested solutions but none works. Could anyone here know how to solve this?

Solutions attempted: [My website shows up as a blank page on my desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418893/my-website-shows-up-as-a-blank-page-on-my-desktop)

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/

Comment: Can you access the backend or is the /wp-admin also showing as a white page? The fact it shows the old files sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: I can't see the admin page either. I have cleared cache on my browsers but i still encounter the same problem. Is there a way I can clean up the domain cache?

Comment: Just to clarify, the blank page is it on the wordpress website or when you access cpanel?

Comment: @Aravona sorry. For the WordPress site.

Comment: without being able to access the back end, can you disable the plugins, amend your theme to twentyfifteen and check the home / site urls in the wp-options table to confirm everything is ok there?